# When voting with a slow internet connection, it can get counted towards the next round

Tags: bug, april-fools, connectivity, stackegg

While playing StackEgg, if i cast a vote towards the end of the round when i have a slow connection, it can get counted towards the next round. Then, in the next round, it tells me that i already voted in that round, when really i meant to vote on the previous round.

My internet connection is a little better now, so i can't reproduce it ATM.

Comment: I think it has to do with the million requests fired by the game. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Important to use the [tag:april-fools] tag otherwise people would think there is a bug with actual voting.

Comment: It's only going to become worse - my guess is that there are less than 100 people playing, and it's the start of the business day in the eastern US.  Over the next four hours the load will ramp up at least 4x the current load.

Comment: We're working on it: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/582889433508253696