# Really slow load/response times on Stack Overflow, MSO, MSE, many (all?) others

Tags: support, connectivity

Intermittently since about 10:00 BST (9:00 GMT) today. I don't see anything on https://www.stackstatus.net/ I'm connecting from the UK.

Comment: I'm guessing it's stackegg.  Hopefully the wizards are tackling the load right now to see if it can be reduced without ruining the game.

Comment: No idea why they're not shutting it down until they figure a way to handle it.

Comment: It's all sites - Programmers, PM, Workplace, Personal Productivity, SO, and Meta.SE are all really slow for me. I can't confirm/deny that it's Stack Egg, but if it is, it should go off. It's actually painful for me to moderate Programmers, much less participate as a user. If I was a new user, this kind of site performance would make me leave.

Comment: Needs a dedicated site, then...

Comment: There's a big storm over central Europe right now. It certainly has caused some power outages already, so maybe some CDN nodes have been affected (by power or connection loss)?

Comment: And for what it's worth, I'm in the US. Physically in Massachusetts, but the work proxy is in Connecticut.

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/582889433508253696

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252377/when-voting-with-a-slow-internet-connection-it-can-get-counted-towards-the-next

Comment: Yeah, StackEgg went off and now [so] is offline. UK, Cambridge.

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/582900535122104320

Answer (score 7):

> Not a graph that anyone in IT wants to see... it doesn't even matter what it is or what the scale is: *not good*
>
> [image]

https://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/582908566979383296

Comment: You just lost the game.

Comment: Now that stackegg has been re-enabled, how's it looking?  And what was the fix for this attempt?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, it's only been disabled on SO (and perhaps other big and/or most-active-player sites?).

Comment: Spoiler: it's the amount of sessions on the server. :)

Comment: "http session count; the flat line is our configured ceiling" > okay, so one game just put the entire web server upside down :)

Answer (score 2):

I just disabled the StackEgg and it seems the pages on my end are loading a lot faster. I am not sure, but it seems there is quite some traffic while not interacting with it.

(How to disable? See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289039/993547))

---

**Update 15:45:**

[They now disabled the StackEgg](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/582900535122104320) since that seems to be the problem (as expected). Hopefully all connections restore to what they should be.

Comment: But the link takes too long to load... :)

Comment: Ehhhrrr. They took down SO. It seems SO is the root cause of the Egg problem ;)

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/582900535122104320

Comment: Hoorah!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

[SE has identified and corrected the problem](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/582920786412998656), and will continue to monitor throughout the day to be sure the eggs don't crack in other ways...

From the link:

[image]